# Original Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

You may find me fast:
My answer is transparent
to those restive few who went off
Their egregious oversight
Left to scan and screen

Hear my refrain
bound to draw the story out

Hint #1

> Please stop trying to edit the title. It's one of the clues.

Hint #2

> As @Mea Culpa Nay pointed out, there is a contradiction. So many contradictions, in fact, that it's almost moronic.

Hint #3

> My last clue is a Herring. Does that make me two-faced?

Hint #4

> I am what I am, and I am what I am not.

Comment: There is a contradiction: Title says it is a _riddle_ however, *riddle* tag was not applied. This looks fishy! :-)

Comment: I can't help but think... it almost sounds like haiku... but not quite.

Comment: Still no correctly found answer to this, can you provide any more clues?

Comment: Any clue, @Dedwards? Perhaps as a very late Christmas present ;)

Comment: Very well, @Aryaman. Fourth clue added.

Comment: I've just added another answer (2 in total), but I still think I'm far off. Does having a really hard riddle indicate that the riddle is really good, or really bad? :P

Comment: @Aryaman, My anxiety and I would both like to know that, too.

Comment: @Dedwards rot13(Jnvg, vf gur nafjre Nakvrgl?)

Comment: @Aryaman Unun! Ab, vg'f abg. V whfg jbeel gung zl "qvssvphyg" evqqyrf ner ernyyl whfg cbbeyl jevggra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me put out this fine puzzle comprises of

> auto-antonyms (contronyms)  - words with opposite meanings.

You may find me fast

> fast: fixed in place, moving quickly.

My answer is transparent

> transparent: invisible, obvious.

to those restive few who went off

> restive: restless, reluctant to move.
>  off: deactivated, activated as in an alarm.

Their egregious oversight

> egregious: outrageously bad, outstanding.
>  oversight: watchful care, overlooking.

left to scan and screen

> left: departed, remaining.
>  scan: examine closely, glance at.
>  screen: show, conceal.

Hear my refrain

> refrain: desist, repeat.

bound to draw the story out

> bound: restrained, a leap.
>  draw: close or open curtains.
>  out: visible (stars), invisible (light).

Title and hints: Original riddle

> Original may mean an old origin or newly created, and a riddle has parallel opposite expressions. The hints allude to the contradictory nature of these words, and two-faced clues that these are also called Janus words.

Comment: I had given up hope...

Answer (score 4):

Attempt #2:

Word:

> Lie

You may find me fast:

> Example, the liar quickly finds a false answer to give in response to an inquiry.

My answer is transparent:

> Bad lie, obvious lie, white lie (immediately known as a lie upon reception). Or more literally, a lie has no substance.

to those restive few who went off:

> ?

Their egregious oversight:

> Either the liar made a mistake in telling the lie (by telling a bad lie or messed up a detail etc.), or the receiver missed that it was a lie.

Left to scan and screen:

> The liar or receiver could be mulling over the lie and the details.

Hear my refrain:

> Lies could be told to avoid or end a discussion.

bound to draw the story out:

> When the lie is discovered, the whole situation blows up into something bigger than before.

Hint 1:

> Maybe this isn't an original riddle?

Hint 2:

> The contradictions could be deliberate acts of misinformation, sort of a form of a lie.

Hint 3:

> [Red] Herring - "a misleading clue" (a small lie). Two-Faced: "deceitful or hypocritical."

---

Maybe this is silly, but I think the answer is:

> Transparent

You may find me fast:
My answer is transparent

> literally telling us the answer

to those restive few who went off
Their egregious oversight
Left to scan and screen

> Kept reading instead of just taking the answer given in the first two lines

Hear my refrain
bound to draw the story out

> Again, "I wrote this to distract you"

Comment: This is beautiful.

Comment: Ha! I knew someone would guess this. I love it, but it's not correct.

Comment: :) well, I've now added a second attempt.

Comment: So very, very close!

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> An X-Ray?

You may find me fast:

> An x-ray examination is over in a flash

My answer is transparent

> X-Rays see through things... but also old-fashioned hospital x-rays were put onto a transparency to view on an OHP.

Left to scan and screen

> An x-ray could also be referred to as a *scan* or *screening*.

bound to draw the story out

> The results of an x-ray could lead to a more lengthy hospital procedure.

The title "Original Riddle"

> Not sure on this, but an x-ray transparency is also a form of photographic negative. Negatives are the "original".

Comment: Interesting answer. Definitely not on of the answers I thought I'd get.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a long shot but I guess the answer is:

> Words

You find me fast:

> When you read a word it quickly disappears from your sight as you read another word, just as someone who says a word, you will only hear it briefly then it disappears.

My answer is transparent

> The answer is right in front of you, the riddle is made up of words, but at first you cant see it (transparent) until you solve the it.

to those restive few who went off
Their egregious oversight

*Not sure with this one:*

> For someone who does not have the patience to peruse the riddle and gives up will be really bad at solving the riddle. - Not sure how this fits in with the answer

Left to scan and screen

> if you look at the computer screen you can see it contains lots of words.

Hear my refrain

> As a noun refrain means a repeated line or sentences in a poem, sentences are made up from words.

bound to draw the story out

> Words can be written, meaning they are bound to paper or any other medium on which they are written including a computer screen, they are used to tell stories.

Comment: Yep, it's a word, but a pretty specific one. :P

Answer (score 1):

Well, a possible answer could be

> Light ray(s) / a beam of light / electro-magnetic radiation

As,
You may find me fast:

> Light is the fastest, in fact!

My answer is transparent

> Light is one component which makes things transparent or not

to those restive few who went off

> Not sure on this part

Their egregious oversight

> Could be persons with myopia / hyper-metropia

Left to scan and screen

> These two actions require light source and with a magnifying-glass for scanning

Hear my refrain

> short/medium/FM waves and other variants(such as microwaves) of  EM radiation can be used to ...

bound to draw the story out

> scan / xerox / reproduce / boil in a oven (to get the extract of an edible item)... though bit stretched.

Comment: maybe the restive few could mean rot13(ersenpgvba bs yvtug)?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Good guess though.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is:

> A Riddle!

You may find me fast:

My answer is transparent

> You can find the answer to a riddle pretty fast if you just happen to think in the right direction. The answer is also "transparent," i.e obvious (once you get to know the answer, at least :P )

to those restive few who went off

Their egregious oversight

Left to scan and screen

> Some "restive" (which means people who're too restless, by the way) people may over think the answers. A true testament of Puzzling.Stackexchange.

Hear my refrain

bound to draw the story out

> Riddles often use repetition etc, similar to poems and songs. They also try to complicate things and make an entire story out of a word.

Also...

> This sorta explains why the poster was adamant about keeping the title as is, and the comment about it not being tagged as a riddle etc.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that came to mind was

> fata morgana

You may find me fast:

> in the desert (or just very hot days) you see them a lot

My answer is transparent

> Fata morgana's are not real or transparent

to those restive few who went off
Their egregious oversight

> When people see a fata morgana they think they are saved and found water and will try to get to it as fast as possible although they will never reach

Left to scan and screen

> Referring to having to search for real water

Hear my refrain
bound to draw the story out

> In the end if you keep going after fata morgana's your end will come fast

Hints:

Original Riddle

> I think hint 1 & 2 might go together as in a fata morgana is not the original thing that you are looking for it's a fake version of it that is not real which is a contradiction of the title.

My last clue is a Herring. Does that make me two-faced?

> I was thinking again of two-faced as in it is not real but it looks real.

Comment: Very cool answer, but not the right one either.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer based on Durrolf's answer,

> The truth

You may find me fast:

> You may find truth and the real story quickly.

My answer is transparent

> Truth is an open book.

to those restive few who went off
Their egregious oversight
Left to scan and screen

> You try and find out the truth from liars.

Hear my refrain
bound to draw the story out

> Truth will give you the straight answer.

Hint 1

> Many riddles have the answer "truth"

Hint 2 and 3

> The answer sounds like it could be a lie?

Hint 4

> ?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is:

> Lightning and Thunder

You may find me fast:

> I do find lightning fast. Lighting is just about the fastest thing around!

My answer is transparent

> Thunder is a sound, therefore not visible.

to those restive few who went off
Their egregious oversight
Left to scan and screen

> Thinking back to "Original Riddle" I thought of early humans trying to understand the natural world. Some would have gone to try to find the source of the Lightning and Thunder, looking and trying to understand.

Hear my refrain
bound to draw the story out

> When lightning stops (refrains) you hear thunder. Maybe a bit of a stretch there, but it also is a bit like a song's chorus, or refrain, in that it repeats after each lightning bolt.

Answer (score 1):

This may be thin, but are you

> An oxymoron?

Because

> Most of the riddle is composed of oxymorons ("those restive few who went off" etc) and the answer is simply drawn by describing the riddle, which makes it transparent. Also, Hint #2 says that the answer is almost moronic -> (oxy)moron.

No clue about the title though.

Comment: So very, very close.

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess, but I think the answer is:

> A Mirror

I think this is the right answer because...

> @Dorrulf suggested "transparent," to which the original poster replied stating that he was very close. It also makes a lot of sense in terms of the clues...

You may find me fast:

> Mirrors are quite common and are easy to find.

My answer is transparent

to those restive few who went off

> A Mirror is symbolically transparent since it doesn't hide your flaws.

Their egregious oversight

Left to scan and screen

> Looking at yourself can lead to a realisation of your flaws or "oversights." We're left staring at ourselevs, aka "scan and screen" ourseleves.

Hear my refrain

bound to draw the story out

> "Refrain" could mean the infinite mirror thing you get when you place two mirrors opposite to each other. The second line could be, again, a reference to how we get to see our own stories when we look at ourselves in the mirror. OR, this could just be OP being dramatic :P

**What about the Hints?**

> Honestly, any logic I have would be stretching it. Hint #4 could be true for a mirror, since it shows both what the object is, and what the object could be (*metaphorically.* :P ). Hint #1 could be the fact that mirros show us our true selves, "orginal." Hint#3 contradicts Hint #2, so maybe we can ignore both of them? :P

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> Duplicity.

You may find me fast:
My answer is transparent

> If we look with care, duplicity can be found out quickly. Lies are transparent, they can be easily seen through.

to those restive few who went off
Their egregious oversight

> As said, the answer is duplicity. Calm people don’t usually oversee things, and the truth  is transparent to them.

Left to scan and screen

> Duplicity has to be scanned and screened to find the truth.

Hear my refrain
bound to draw the story out

> This was a *lie*. Duplicity does not tell you the real story.

Hint #4

> Duplicity is duplicity , however you spin it. But you have to be original in duplicity to avoid being caught.

Title:

> Original is the opposite of *duplicate*, another form of duplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is:

> The cover to a book or novel

You may find me fast

> Book covers can help attract readers and are often the first part of a book spotted by customers/patrons.

My answer is transparent / to those restive few who went off / Their egregious oversight / Left to scan and screen

> "You can't judge a book by its cover," so the saying goes. Those who do not take the time to investigate a book (particularly a novel) will continue to wander and search the shelves without knowing what's written on the pages within.

Hear my refrain /
bound to draw the story out

> A book is "bound" by the spine, which isn't exactly the cover, but it's connected. "Refrain" could refer to the title of the book.

Original Riddle

> "Cover" can be juxtaposed with "original," which admittedly makes sense in the context of music more so than literature.
>
>  Apparently, a [cover story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_story) is also a thing.

Comment: Isn't the meaning of Cover Story very different than "Covering" a song in music?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> [logical-deduction](/questions/tagged/logical-deduction)

You may find me fast:

> Logic **can** be fast to be deducted

My answer is transparent

> Truth and False has no colour, do they?

to those restive few who went off

> The truth-searchers

Their egregious oversight

> Overseeing clues in logical deduction can mislead you **BADLY**...

Left to scan and screen

> So scan and screen the clues carefully!

Hear my refrain
bound to draw the story out

> To deduce the truth